# Horizontal Navigation Dropdown menu with Javascript & JSON

Tags: javascript, json

How do I get the dropdown to appear on my horizontal navigation menu? Using pure JS with no jquery.

Here is my code:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var nav = "navigation.json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var myNav = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        mainNav(myNav);
    }
 }
xmlhttp.open("GET", nav, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function mainNav(arr) {

var out = ""
var i;

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
    out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' +
    arr[i].display + '</a>';
    }
document.getElementById("navlinks").innerHTML = out;
}
```

I have my JSON file being called from AJAX. But here is a snippet of my JSON Data.

```
[
{
"display":"COMPANY ADDRESS",
"url":"",
"sub":[
    {
        "display":"2014-2015",
        "url":""
    },
    {
        "display":"2013-2014",
        "url":""
    },
    {
        "display":"2012-2013",
        "url":""
    },
    {
        "display":"2011-2012",
        "url":""
    }
]
```

Comment: What issues are you having? Not sure if this is a problem, but your JSON snippet isn't valid JSON.

Comment: I"m trying to create a dropdown when the user over the navigation. As of now, it only displays the top level.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: The `,` after `"url":""` makes the JSON invalid, as @admdrew stated, BTW.

Comment: Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ggyab1tb/
My accomplishment is trying to make the navigation to show a drop down, once hover. Example, hovering over "COMPANY ADDRESS" will show 2014-2015, 2013-2014, and so on.